# Passing types to a component and forwarding that type to a factory

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a factory method using Angular 2 and TypeScript, but I'm obviously not doing it the right way because my TSC compiler is throwing a spurious error:

```
error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

I am trying to pass a type as an `@Input()` to a component like this:

```
<custom-user [componentType]="CreateMeComponent"></custom-user>
```

I have this code:

```
// custom-user.component.ts
export class GalleriaCustomUserComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() componentType: any; // is there a type for types, other than any?
    @ViewChild(ComponentDirective) componentAnchor: ComponentDirective;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.componentAnchor
            .createComponent<this.componentType>(); // this line throws the ',' error
    }
}
```

And the directive looks like this:

```
// component.directive.ts 
@Directive({
    selector: '[componentAnchor]'
})
export class ComponentDirective {
    constructor(
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) {}

    public createComponent<MyComponent>() {  
        this.viewContainer.clear();

        let componentFactory =
            this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
        let componentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);

        return componentRef;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or is it a bad design?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use type names in view bindings. Only references to the component instance or template variables is supported. Assign the type to a property of the component, then you can use it:

```
<custom-user [componentType]="createMeComponent"></custom-user>
```

```
createMeComponent = CreateMeComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case, is it possible to get a type that can be passed to a generic method based on a type's name?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about TS generics. I'm not actually using TS with Angular2.

Comment: Ok. Alternatively, is is possible to call ```ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory()``` with a string of the type name rather than the type itself?

Comment: No, that's not supported. You can maintain a map from string to type (for example using a shared service) to be able to map from a string to a `Type` yourself.